# Remove word from a comma separated values of specific field

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

The `NIS` group file has format

```
group1:*:100:bat,cat,zat,ratt
group2:*:200:rat,cat,bat
group3:*:300:rat
```

With `:` as delimiter, need to remove exact word (for example `rat`) from 4th column. Any leading or trailing `,` to the word should be deleted as well to preserve comma separated values format in 4th column

**Expected output:**

```
group1:*:100:bat,cat,zat,ratt
group2:*:200:cat,bat
group3:*:300:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `perl` solution is okay:

Modified sample input to add more relevant cases..

```
$ cat ip.txt 
group1:*:100:bat,cat,zat,ratt
group2:*:200:rat,cat,bat
group3:*:300:rat
group4:*:400:mat,rat,sat
group5:*:500:pat,rat

$ perl -F: -lane '(@a) = split/,/,$F[3]; $F[3] = join ",", grep { $_ ne "rat" } @a; print join ":", @F' ip.txt
group1:*:100:bat,cat,zat,ratt
group2:*:200:cat,bat
group3:*:300:
group4:*:400:mat,sat
group5:*:500:pat
```

- `-F:` split input line on `:` and save to `@F` array
- `(@a) = split/,/,$F[3]` split 4th column on `,` and save to `@a` array
- `$F[3] = join ",", grep { $_ ne "rat" } @a` remove elements in `@a` array exactly matching `rat`, join those elements with `,` and modify 4th field of input line
- `print join ":", @F` print the modified `@F` array elements joined by `:`

Golfing to avoid the temp array `@a`

```
$ perl -F: -lane '$F[3] = join ",", grep { $_ ne "rat" } split/,/,$F[3]; print join ":", @F' ip.txt
```

Using regex on 4th column:

```
$ perl -F: -lane '$F[3] =~ s/,rat\b|\brat(,|\b)//g; print join ":", @F' ip.txt 
group1:*:100:bat,cat,zat,ratt
group2:*:200:cat,bat
group3:*:300:
group4:*:400:mat,sat
group5:*:500:pat
```

Comment: Sundeep how can i do this in loop , we need to clean up 100 of names

Comment: got it, `perl -i -F: -lane '(@a) = split/,/,$F[3]; $F[3] = join ",", grep { $_ ne "rat" } @a; print join ":", @F' group1`

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use awk for this job. Try this (GNU awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=":"} {gsub (/\yrat,?\y|\y,?rat\y/, "", $4)}1' file
```

Using `:` as field separator, `gsub` removes all `rat` in 4th field. `\y` is used for word boundaries so that `rat` will match but not `rrat`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\brat\b,?//g' file
```

Remove one or more words `rat` followed by a possible `,`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>1{sub(/rat,*/,"")}1' file

group1:*:100:bat,cat,zat,ratt
group2:*:200:cat,bat
group3:*:300:
```